# When exporting a Feature, how can I turn off all page cache related settings?

Tags: features, strongarm

I’m trying to export a Feature that would be used in a typical development environment. I want to have anything related to page caching turned off. But on the create feature page I’m not seeing where to do this. I would have thought there would be a Strongarm variable that reads Cache pages for anonymous users but there isn’t one. Also looking for the same for ‘Aggregate and compress CSS files’ and ‘Aggregate JavaScript files’.

So to clarify, how can I export the following in a Feature?

Cache pages for anonymous users -> OFF

Aggregate and compress CSS files -> OFF

Aggregate JavaScript files -> OFF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables are named:

- cache - *Cache pages for anonymous users*
- preprocess_css - *Aggregate and compress CSS files.*
- preprocess_js - *Aggregate JavaScript files.*